# Kubernetes Service account issue in airflow 2.4.2

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow

We have to start our kubernetes pod in a separate namespace.This namespace will be different from namespace in which airflow is running.This is for applying istio injection on that separate namespace.We are using kubernetes executor.

We tried two approaches:

1. In pythonoperator specified executor_config with namespace specified .This did not work and pod started in same namespace as airflow.
2. In kubernetepodoperator we specified namespace and a service account with permissions to that namespace .But default service account within namespace where airflow is deployed is being used , because of this we are getting forbidden error on that service account.

Is there something we are missing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it is very late since I asked this question, I am updating the steps we took to solve the issue. We provided the read and write access of new namespace to deafult service account created with airflow installation. For this we had to create a role with permissions required on new namespace and bind that to the default service account.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you upgraded the Kubernetes provider version to `5.0`. There were breaking changes with the provider, and the configuration that previously lived in the Airflow configuration under the [kubernetes] has been removed. To fix this, you will need to pass the kube config as a parameter with the `config_file` parameter. Additionally, you need to pass the `kubernetes_conn_id` parameter that is used to connect to Kubernetes using Airflow.

References:

- [The breaking changes in Kubernetes Provider](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/CHANGELOG.rst#500)
- How to connect to [Kubernetes using Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/connections/kubernetes.html#howto-connection-kubernetes)